# How to integrate stripe with react-native expo sdk36 without ejecting?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments

I am reading:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/payments/
- https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/running-apple-pay-on-a-real-device.html
- https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/21
- https://pusher.com/tutorials/react-native-payments
- https://medium.com/@lyzhovnik/using-stripe-payment-service-with-react-native-and-fetch-4177c8d992cb
- https://github.com/expo/stripe-expo

I want to integrate stripe payment within a react-native app build with expo sdk 36.

My project **is not ejected** and I would like to keep it so I can still run and debug iOS app without needing apple hardware. *(it's for developer experience, but I want to see if there's a way before squeezing that.)*

1. To me, it seems that stripe just need an HTTP client to communicate, while I have fetch, am I correct?
2. Why **exactly** do I need to eject, what native library do I need to plug and why the http client is not sufficient?

   - How can I integrate stripe to target all of the platforms (web/ios/native) with the less effort (what library should I get started with to resolve my goal.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expo really doesn't support the expo-payments-stripe module for React Native in managed workflow. Although there is a little trick. You can implement it by using a WebView, as (for example) this npm-module does: [expo-stripe-checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-stripe-checkout). This module uses Stripe Checkout.

Regarding your question about using a normal HTTP-Client, maybe this article helps: [Using Stripe API in React Native with fetch](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html)

I hope this helps!

**EDIT:**
Stripe just released the official Stripe client library for React Native as public beta: [stripe-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native). I would suggest looking into that.

Comment: I can't see anyone mentioning [stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react). Why not though?

Comment: This module is made for React, not React Native, so it isn't going to work. But Stripe just released the official Stripe client library for React Native as public beta: [stripe-react-native](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native). I'd take a look into that.